# Accessing APK files from unrooted Android device

Tags: android, eclipse, performance, storage, apk

How can we access the APK files from an unrooted device and copy it to the external storage ?

Any guidance will be great,

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copy APK from source package path to your sdcard using this function(no need root access)

```
public static boolean copyFile(String srcFilePath, String destFilePath)
     {
     boolean success = false;

     if(srcFilePath!=null && destFilePath!=null)
     {
     srcFilePath = srcFilePath.trim();
     destFilePath = destFilePath.trim();

     if(!srcFilePath.equals("") && !destFilePath.equals("") && !srcFilePath.equals(destFilePath))
     {
     File srcFile = new File(srcFilePath);

     if(srcFile.exists() && srcFile.isFile())
     {
     try
     {
     File destFile = new File(destFilePath);
     InputStream in = new FileInputStream(srcFile);
     OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destFile);

    // Transfer bytes from in to out
     byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
     int len;
     while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0)
     {
     out.write(buf, 0, len);
     }

     in.close();
     out.close();
     success = true;
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
     e.printStackTrace();
     }
     }
     }
     }
     return success;
     }
```